# How to fix error of Undefined offset: 2 using list explode

Tags: php

```
list($s1,$s2,$s3)=explode("-",$EndDate);
```

It is showing:-

> Undefined offset: 2 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\finishingbrands_new\include\checkReportDates.php on
>   line 3

Comment: Need more code. What is enddate for example?

Comment: 2017-06-03 this is the value in EndDate

Comment: Are you sure? https://3v4l.org/BIJai

Comment: Duplicate what?

Comment: If you remove one part of the date you get the error as you say. https://3v4l.org/AmbKP

Comment: Do like this: var_dump($EndDate); and copy paste the output here. I do not believe you have the value you say in enddate.

Comment: show us the exact output of `var_dump($EndDate);`

Comment: @Ammy can we get the output?

Answer (score 0):

There are three parameters in the `list($s1, $s2, $s3)`, but the `$EndDate` could be exploded into two array. So the first index of the exploded array will be assigned to `$s1`. Similarly, the second will be assigned to `$s2`, and the third will be assigned to `$s2`. As there is no index of `2`, php certainly raise a `notice: Undefined offset: 2`.

Comment: Did you see the link I posted above? It works without problems

Comment: How it explode to two array as the value in $EndDate is 2017-06-03

Comment: @Ammy If `$EndDate` is 2017-06-03, you couldn't get the notice. Check the source of you data.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have incorrect data in $EndDate.

The code runs without problems with 2016-06-03
https://3v4l.org/BIJai

But if we remove one part of the date we get the error you say.

2017-06 returns error.
https://3v4l.org/AmbKP